# Rutas manuales y configuración por defecto no funcionan con Vite

Tags: reactjs, vite

Hice una aplicación de react con vite y la navegación me funciona bien, salvo cuando intento hacerlo manualmente: si por ejemplo intento entrar `example.com/3` pues me sale un error de que no lo ha encontrado la ruta. ¿Hay que hacer algún tipo de configuración en vite? Lo tengo por default.

Esta sería la página de ejemplo `https://example-orcin.vercel.app/third` para que veáis el error.

**Código de ejemplo App.jsx**

```
import { Link, Route, Switch } from "wouter";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link href="/">Uno</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link href="/second">Dos</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link href="/third">Tres</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={Index} />
        <Route path="/second" component={Second} />
        <Route path="/third" component={Third} />
      </Switch>
    </>
  );

  function Index() {
    return <h1>Hola 1</h1>;
  }
  function Second() {
    return <h1>Hola 2</h1>;
  }
  function Third() {
    return <h1>Hola 3</h1>;
  }
}
export default App;
```

***Código de ejemplo vite.config.js***

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()]
})
```

Comment: No entiendo cuál es el error. Entro a la ruta `https://example-orcin.vercel.app/third` y veo el "Hola 3" correctamente.